# How to prevent changes of GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG in /etc/default/grub

Tags: linux, grub2, rhel8, dnf, rocky-linux

With Rocky Linux 8.4 (clone of RHEL 8.4) in /etc/default/grub I have GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=false

A “dnf update” that included grub2-tools changed it back to GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true

Is there some way to prevent this from happening in future grub2-tools updates?
Note that the update didn’t change other entries back to their default values. For example, it kept my GRUB_TIMEOUT=20

Thanks!

Comment: Have had this same problem with AlmaLinux. Seems as if something is forcing an update and I would prefer to not have to brute force lock permissions on this file and understand why/what is happening.